# Chat Server (Network Programming in C)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have made the following chat server program in c. The Problem is that as soon as I run my client and 'Client Says :-' is displayed on the Client Screen, the server immediately displays 'Client Says :-', 'Server Says :-' without waiting for the Client to give the input and then process it and the program doesnot work after that no matter what I input.

I want my Client to ask for input then send it to server , The server should then display the Client's input and ask for it's own input. This should go on until anyone of them enters 'bye'.

//Chat Server

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main()
{
   int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   if(sockfd<0)
   {
    perror("Error in Creating Socket\n");
    exit(-1);
   }

   struct sockaddr_in server,client;

   bzero(&server,sizeof(server));
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = htons(10000);
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;



   if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))<0)
   {
       perror("Error in Socket Binding\n");
       exit(-1);
   }

   if(listen(sockfd,5)<0)
   {
    perror("Error in Listening\n");
    exit(-1);
   }

   printf("Listening\n");

   char clientsent[500];
   char bhago[5] = "exit";
   bhago[5] = '\0';
   char serverinput[500];

   while(1)
   {
    int acceptfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)sizeof(client));

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)//child process is executing
    {  

        close(sockfd);

        while(1)
        {

            bzero(&serverinput, 500);
            bzero(&clientsent, 500);

            int n = recv(acceptfd, clientsent,500,0);

            printf("Client Says :-\n");
            printf("%s",clientsent);


            if(strcmp(clientsent,bhago) == 0)
            {
                close(acceptfd);
                exit(0);
            }


            printf("Server Says :-\n");

            int x = 0;

            do{

                serverinput[x]=getchar();
                x++;
              }while(x-1 != '\n');

            send(acceptfd, serverinput, 500, 0);

            if(strcmp(serverinput,bhago) == 0)
            {
                close(acceptfd);
                exit(0);
            }

        }
    }
    close(acceptfd);
   }
}
```

//Chat Client

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main()
{

   int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   if(sockfd<0)
   {
    perror("Error in Creating Socket\n");
    exit(-1);
   }

   struct sockaddr_in server;

   bzero(&server,sizeof(server));
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = htons(10000);
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))<0)
   {
    perror("Error in Connection\n");
    exit(-1);
   }

   printf("Connection Established\n");

   char clientinput[500];
   char bhago[5] = "exit";
   bhago[5] = '\0';
   char serversent[500];

   while(1)
   {

    bzero(&clientinput, 500);
    bzero(&serversent, 500);

    printf("Client Says :-\n");

    int x = 0;
    do{

        clientinput[x]=getchar();
        x++;
          }while(x-1 != '\n');

        send(sockfd, clientinput, 500, 0);

        if(strcmp(clientinput, bhago) == 0)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Server Said :-\n");

        recv(sockfd, serversent, 500,0);

        printf("%s",serversent);

        if(strcmp(serversent, bhago) == 0)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
   }
close(sockfd);
}//main
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of number of characters recv'd by your `recv` function - check it's return value

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of `0`-terminated `char`-arrays, also know as C-"strings", on which all the `str*()` functions work.

Comment: Also you ***really*** want to check the return value of all relevant systems calls, which in the context of the source shown do include `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: To cap it off, wasteful, cargo-cult 'bzero' calls.

Comment: Here the missing question mark to my 1st comment: "*?*"

Comment: @alk lol.......  I assumed you had overwritten it with a NUL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the latter of those two lines

```
char bhago[5] = "exit";
bhago[5] = '\0';
```

invokes undefined behaviour by writing out of `bhago`'s bounds by accessing the 6th element, with `bhago` being 5 elements wide. From now on anything can happen.

In C arrays' indexes are `0`-based. The 1st element here is `bhago[0]`.

---

And this

```
  ..., (socklen_t*)sizeof(client));
```

is plain horrible wrong. Do not *blindly* cast away compilation errors. A pointer is expected and the code passes a compile-time constant, invoking undefined behaviour again here. I'd expect the code to die with execution of this line immediately.

`accept()` expects a `socklen_t *` as last parameter, so pass one:

```
  socklen_t socklen = sizeof client;
  ..., &socklen));
```